# How can I get the same result without using Bootstrap?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I found a code in an article on the web, the live demonstration can be seen in the following [link](http://www.itidabhoi.org/demo/bootstrap-crud-php/)

Investigating I was able to create a simple modal using a few lines of jquery and CSS, without using bootstrap

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/br19232c/1/

```js
$(function() {
 //----- OPEN
 $('[data-modal-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
  var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-open');
  $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

  e.preventDefault();
 });

 //----- CLOSE
 $('[data-modal-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
  var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-close');
  $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

```css
.content {
 max-width:800px;
 width:100%;
 margin:0px auto;
 margin-bottom:60px;
}

/* Outer */
.modal {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99999;
}

/* Inner */
.modal-inner {
 width: 500px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #fff;
}

/* Close Button */
.modal-close {
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 padding-top:4px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 right:0px;
 transition:ease 0.25s all;
 -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
 transform:translate(50%, -50%);
 border-radius:1000px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:100%;
 color:#fff;
}

.modal-close:hover {
 -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
 transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
 background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn" data-modal-open="modal-1" href="#">Open Modal</a>

<div class="modal" data-modal="modal-1">
    <div class="modal-inner">
        <h2>Wow! This is Awesome!</h2>
        <p>Donec in volutpat nisi. In quam lectus, aliquet rhoncus cursus a, congue et arcu. Vestibulum tincidunt neque id nisi pulvinar aliquam. Nulla luctus luctus ipsum at ultricies. Nullam nec velit dui. Nullam sem eros, pulvinar sed pellentesque ac, feugiat et turpis. Donec gravida ipsum cursus massa malesuada tincidunt. Nullam finibus nunc mauris, quis semper neque ultrices in. Ut ac risus eget eros imperdiet posuere nec eu lectus.</p>
        <p><a data-modal-close="modal-1" href="#">Close</a></p>
        <a class="modal-close" data-modal-close="modal-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the original code of the live demonstration article

I have disabled the bootstrap plugins and of course it was supposed to stop working...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           $('#insert').val("Insert");  
           $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"fetch.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                dataType:"json",  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#name').val(data.name);  
                     $('#address').val(data.address);  
                     $('#gender').val(data.gender);  
                     $('#designation').val(data.designation);  
                     $('#age').val(data.age);  
                     $('#employee_id').val(data.id);  
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                     $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
                }  
           });  
      });  
      $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  
           if($('#name').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Name is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#address').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Address is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#designation').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Designation is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#age').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Age is required");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"insert.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form').serialize(),  
                     beforeSend:function(){  
                          $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
                     },  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                          $('#add_data_Modal').modal('hide');  
                          $('#employee_table').html(data);  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(employee_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"select.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
                          $('#dataModal').modal('show');  
                     }  
                });  
           }            
      });  
 });
```

```html
<?php  
 $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id,name FROM tbl_employee ORDER BY id DESC");
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Webslesson Tutorial | PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</title>  
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <div align="right">  
                          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>  
                     </div>  
                     <br />  
                     <div id="employee_table">  
                          <table class="table table-bordered">  
                               <tr>  
                                    <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">Edit</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">View</th>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                               ?>  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               }  
                               ?>  
                          </table>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Enter Employee Name</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Employee Address</label>  
                          <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Select Gender</label>  
                          <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">  
                               <option value="Male">Male</option>  
                               <option value="Female">Female</option>  
                          </select>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Designation</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Age</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

You could use my modal which is a simple example

Despite having created a simple modal, it can be said that I have a high knowledge of jQuery development, but sadly it is not, I do not know for sure the use of ajax and I do not know how to use of libraries Bootstrap . what makes it difficult for me to be able to guide myself in its javascript code to adapt what I have created.

So how can I make it work the same, without using Bootstrap, (not so much the design, but if its structure is to say when clicking on edit that the data is displayed in the dialog box etc...)

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: your question is very wide. do you want to create a modal without using bootstrap, then you can google for other jquery modal plugins. or do you want to fetch the data in the modal after edit clicked.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava I do not want to create a modal, the modal as you can see I have already created it, the idea is to avoid the use of plugins when that work can be developed on its own.

Comment: so you want to fetch the data into modal

Comment: @AtalShrivastava What I want is to look for the data when clicking on edit or view or add that is to say that this data is shown similar to the live demonstration only without using bootstrap

Comment: use jquery or ajax methods for data, call your url, put the data in array and display in the text box.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava Yes friend :)

Comment: data doesn't related to bootstrap. bootstrap is a front-end framework, which helps in building scalable app or website. you can write your own code for data.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava But if that were the case, then it would work after having commented on its complements

Comment: @AtalShrivastava Here the problem is that to do this I have to adapt my code of the simple modal with ajax and that is my problem that I do not know how to do it because I have never handled ajax

Comment: commenting bootstrap js and css would stop displaying modal. so if your modal is not in the view, how does your data get display which you put in the modal.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava That makes bootstrap why I said in the question how to get the same results without using bootstrap

Comment: you have created a modal, when click on edit button, write function to display the data in your modal. something like `$("edit").on("click", function(){
    var data = $(url); $("modal").html(data);
     });`

Comment: @AtalShrivastava If I have created a simple modal, but I can not use it in this programming because it must adapt that code to the ajax code as you can see in the original code the data not only works for a simple modal but also comes through ajax, open a window is easy as you can see in my example that I created the problem is how to adapt it to ajax so that it shows those results

Comment: through $.ajax method

Comment: bro you seriously lacking in your js. the solution is right up there in your question.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava and what is the solution according to you, because if it were like this I would not have taken the trouble to ask

Comment: create a on click function when edit is clicked, use `$.ajax({  })` put your url in the ajax call, with that you will get the data in the js, Use  `$('element').val()` to set the value of text boxes.

Comment: If I understand ... in your example you use the jQuery for events registration, fade in/out effect and Ajax calls. And you want to rewrite it with plain JavaScript, do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html `<div` which you want to hide and show give it modal name by adding attribute `data-modal="add_data_modal"`, `add_data_modal` is modal name and used to detect events of add and close. In this div also add  class `modal` and in its inner div add class `modal-inner` so that its css (hide and show) works.

In add Button add attribute `data-modal-open="add_data_modal"`,

In close Button add attribute `data-modal-close="add_data_modal"`

> Note: In all process modal name in div, add button and close button is must be same.

```js
$(function() {
  //----- OPEN
  $('[data-modal-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
    $('#insert_form')[0].reset();
    var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-open');

    $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  //----- CLOSE
  $('[data-modal-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_modal_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-modal-close');
    $('[data-modal="' + targeted_modal_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
  $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#add').click(function(){  

                     $('#employee_id').val("");
                     $('#insert').val("Insert");
           $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(){ 

           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"fetch.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
                dataType:"json"})  
                .done(function(data){  
                     $('#name').val(data.name);  
                     $('#address').val(data.address);  
                     $('#gender').val(data.gender);  
                     $('#designation').val(data.designation);  
                     $('#age').val(data.age);  
                     $('#employee_id').val(data.id);  
                     $('#insert').val("Update");  
                     $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeIn(350);

      
                }).fail(function() {
        alert( "Ajax Request fail" );
      })

            
      });  
      $('#insert_form').on("submit", function(event){  
           event.preventDefault();  

            
           if($('#name').val() == "")  
           {  
                alert("Name is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#address').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Address is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#designation').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Designation is required");  
           }  
           else if($('#age').val() == '')  
           {  
                alert("Age is required");  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"insert.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:$('#insert_form').serialize(), 
                     beforeSend:function(){  
                          $('#insert').val("Inserting");  
                     }
                     })  
                     .done(function(data){  
                         
                          $('#insert_form')[0].reset();  
                              $('[data-modal="add_data_modal"]').fadeOut(350);

                          $('#employee_table').html(data);      
                     })  
                     .fail(function() {
          alert( "Insert ajax request fail" );
          }) 
                  
                  
           }
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.view_data', function(){  
           var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
           if(employee_id != '')  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"select.php",  
                     method:"POST",  
                     data:{employee_id:employee_id}})  
                     .done(function(data){
                            $('[data-modal="empdetail"]').fadeIn(350);
                            $('#employee_detail').html(data);  
      
                     }) .fail(function() {
          alert( "Select ajax request fail" );
          }) 
                     
           }            
      });  
 });
```

```css
.content {
 max-width:800px;
 width:100%;
 margin:0px auto;
 margin-bottom:60px;
}

/* Outer */
.modal {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
 left:0px;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 99999;
}

/* Inner */
.modal-inner {
 width: 500px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: #fff;
}

/* Close Button */
.modal-close {
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 padding-top:4px;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 right:0px;
 transition:ease 0.25s all;
 -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
 transform:translate(50%, -50%);
 border-radius:1000px;
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
 font-size:20px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:100%;
 color:#fff;
}

.modal-close:hover {
 -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
 transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
 background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
                <h3 align="center">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h3>  
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <div align="right">  
                          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-modal-open="add_data_modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>  
                     </div>  
                     <br />  
                     <div id="employee_table">  
                          <table class="table table-bordered">  
                               <tr>  
                                    <th width="70%">Employee Name</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">Edit</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">View</th>  
                               </tr>  
                                <?php  
                               while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                               ?>  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               }  
                               ?>    
                          </table>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
  
<div id="dataModal" class="modal" data-modal="empdetail">  
      <div class="modal-inner">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                      <a class="modal-close" data-modal-close="empdetail" href="#">x</a>
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-modal-close="empdetail">Close</button> 

                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal"  data-modal="add_data_modal">  
      <div class="modal-inner">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                      <a class="modal-close" data-modal-close="add_data_modal" href="#">x</a>

                     <h4 class="modal-title">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Enter Employee Name</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Employee Address</label>  
                          <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Select Gender</label>  
                          <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">  
                               <option value="Male">Male</option>  
                               <option value="Female">Female</option>  
                          </select>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Designation</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Age</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-modal-close="add_data_modal" href="#">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>
```

## Output

**Add Data**

[image: Add Image]

**View Detail using ajax request**
[image: View detail using ajax data]

**Edit data using ajax request**
[image: Edit Data Using Ajax]

> works perfect with PHP and ajax is also works here

Comment: Excellent answer +1, but everything would be perfect if updated answers were given, in this case version 3 of jQuery, a certain part of old code is obsolete, the use of `success` should be replaced by new jQuery controls using `done` and `fail` between plus. Sadly I see many outdated answers and when the same SO asks again they are closed as duplicates among others.

Comment: I have Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this code. It may be useful for you.

```css
.modal-header {
padding: 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.modal-dialog{
      width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.modal-content{
  
  position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.modal-title {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: beige;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}



.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Open Details</a>
</div>



<div id="popup1" class="overlay">  
<div class="popup">
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                    
                     
                     <h4 class="modal-title">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Enter Employee Name</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Employee Address</label>  
                          <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Select Gender</label>  
                          <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">  
                               <option value="Male">Male</option>  
                               <option value="Female">Female</option>  
                          </select>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Designation</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Age</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    
                     <a class="close btn btn-default" href="#">x</a>
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div> 
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This code is good. But How we open or close this pop up with javascript. Because in above code value is updating using javascript than javascript open popup

Comment: @NimsPatel 
The intention is what counts, but its answer is very far from what the user asks, because the user is using a system in conjunction with PHP and ajax, for a simple modal the user already has it linked in his question, so So the question is not based on creating a Modal, but adapting a simple script to the PHP system. But good the use of only CSS deserves a +1

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to use jquery or bootstrap if you are developing only modal-box. Both will cause to download unnecessary js library code and attempt extra http round trip (*it will degrade performance of your site in mobile*).**

Developing your own model box is very easy with only css and javascript, check given link to check more stuff [How create Modal-box](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn; /* Fade in the background */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: slideIn;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    color: white;
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes slideIn {
    from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
    to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0} 
    to {opacity: 1}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Bottom Modal</h2>

<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The intention is what counts, but its answer is very far from what the user asks, because the user is using a system in conjunction with PHP and ajax, for a simple modal the user already has it linked in his question, so So the question is not based on creating a Modal, but adapting a simple script to the PHP system.

Answer (score 0):

After updating above code for open popup using javascript.

```js
function ModalOpen(namee) {
  window.location.href=namee
}
```

```css
.modal-header {
padding: 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.modal-dialog{
      width: 600px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

.modal-content{
  
  position: relative;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 6px;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.modal-title {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: beige;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}



.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="ModalOpen('#popup1')">Check this</button>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay" >  
<div class="popup">
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                    
                     
                     <h4 class="modal-title">PHP Ajax Update MySQL Data Through Bootstrap Modal</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Enter Employee Name</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Employee Address</label>  
                          <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Select Gender</label>  
                          <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">  
                               <option value="Male">Male</option>  
                               <option value="Female">Female</option>  
                          </select>  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Designation</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Age</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                    
                     <a class="close btn btn-default" href="#">x</a>
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div> 
      </div>
 </div>
```